# How to make an NSWindowController run in full screen mode in OSX Lion?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Unsuccessfully, I have searched extensively on how to programatically make an NSWindowController run in full screen mode in OSX Lion.

I even went so far as to buy, "Sams Teach yourself Mac OS X Lion App Development" because chapter/hour 21 was supposed to teach how to do that. I saw some reviews that the code in this book does not often work. I took my chances anyway, ugh!

Here's [a link](http://books.google.com/books?id=Y4LbQI9CfsMC&pg=PT377&lpg=PT377&dq=Sams+Teach+yourself+Mac+OS+X+Lion+App+Development+fullscreen&source=bl&ots=dA58pSCxx_&sig=WTfeZa7p6xWtCNcWOb_Zj51cRNU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jWKPT9b5JYSk8gSOncSkBA&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCA) to a sample of the chapter mentioned above.

Basically, here is what I have for just a test program,based on hour 21 listed above:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface WeatherWindowController : NSWindowController

- (IBAction)toggleFullScreen:(id)sender;

@end
```

I added an NSObject and assigned WeatherWindowController to it.  I have a button that is connected properly as it is logging the NSLog statements properly.

```
#import "WeatherWindowController.h"

@interface WeatherWindowController ()

@end

@implementation WeatherWindowController

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) awakeFromNib{
    self.window.collectionBehavior = NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary;    
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window    has been loaded from its nib file.
}

- (IBAction)toggleFullScreen:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"before toggleFullScreen");
    [self.window toggleFullScreen:sender];
    NSLog(@"after toggleFullScreen");
}
@end
```

Comment: Is your `window` outlet connected in your nib file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need to implement this method in the window controller, since its window will also be in the responder chain, and should therefore receive the action when you choose the “Enter/Exit Full Screen” menu item that you added to your view menu and connected to the First Responder.

So, assuming you've created and so configured that menu item, what *does* happen when you choose it?

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter. I added the Full Screen menu item and it was connected to the toggleFullScreen via First Responder. I ran the app and the full screen menu option was greyed out. On a whim, I changed the IB full screen setting from unsupported to Primary Window, ran it and the full screen menu item was now available and it made the window full screen.

Comment: @Dan: Sounds about right, though the documentation is admittedly vague on the matter. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Sorry Peter, I hit enter by mistake. This was supposed to be the end of the last statement:  However, that is not what I wanted. I wanted the fullscreen availability to be set programmatically, not via a manual IB setting. Any ideas? I thought that setting the self.window.collectionBehavior = NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary; statement in awakeFromNib would accomplish that.

Comment: @Rob your comment above was the answer I was looking for in my situation. I looked up how to mark a comment as the answer and many people thought comments should be comments and answers should be answers only. Please let me know if I should mark this question answered in another way.